# Unit Testing questions

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, unit-testing, flexunit

I just start to study Unit Testing (using FlexUnit). I still have not sure how to use them.

I created a new flex project, and created a class named `Car`. Then, I created a TestCase class, for Car class.

This is the default template that FlexBuilder gave to me, and I put some traces.

```
package flexUnitTests
{
    import flexunit.framework.Assert;

    public class CarTest
    {       
        [Before]
        public function setUp():void
        {
            trace('before test function');
        }

        [After]
        public function tearDown():void
        {
            trace('after test function');
        }

        [BeforeClass]
        public static function setUpBeforeClass():void
        {
            trace('before test class');
        }

        [AfterClass]
        public static function tearDownAfterClass():void
        {
            trace('after test class');
        }

        [Test]
        public function testCar():void
        {
            trace('the test function');

            var c:Car = new Car("gol");

            Assert.assertTrue("Is car name valid:", c.name != "gol");
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand why I have so many methods to run before or after a test function. Why not just use them within a simple funcion, like:

```
        [Test]
        public function testCar():void
        {
            trace('before test class');
            trace('before test function');

            trace('the test function');

            var c:Car = new Car("gol");

            Assert.assertTrue("Is car name valid:", c.name != "gol");

            trace('after test function');
            trace('after test class');
        }
```

A second question I want to add is, these tests test each class individualy, (like shown when instancianting `Car` class) or a I can test my whole application once by instanciating the main class? The problem is how to simulate the whole userflow of the application (user clicks here, send a request to server there, etc, etc). I should write a whole flow one by one in a test method? `:O`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't understand why I have so many methods to run before or after a test function.

You don't *have* to implement all these methods. FB generated all these stubs for you, but you might as well leave them out.

That said, you can have more than one test function inside a test class. You usually test every public function of a class. You may even have multiple tests per function, using different sets of corner-case arguments.
e.g. in your example you only test the constructor, but you might have a test for:

- `car.turnLeft(32)` (in degrees)
- or see what happens when `car.turnLeft(0)`
- or `car.turnLeft(190)` (you're getting on the terrain of `car.turnRight` here)
- or `car.turnLeft(-12)` (negative turnLeft?)

The before/after methods can be used to write some code that you want executed before/after every test in the class, so that you don't have to repeat this in each test function.

> these tests test each class individualy

It is a **unit** test isn't it?

> Can I test my whole application once by instanciating the main class?

That's not what unit tests are for: they only test classes. There are other kinds of testing tools to test (parts of) applications:

- behavioural test tools: in which you write scenario's that contain a typical execution sequences and assert that the outcome of such sequences is correct. I believe [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) can test Flex apps in this way (but not entirely sure)
- UI test tools: in which you record scenario's of users clicking around in your application. These scenario's can then be played back to test whether the application keeps running as expected. [FlexMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/flexmonkey) is one such solution for Flex apps, but it seems the owners have changed direction with the product.